# fetch data from database upto a specific time in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating a web application using c# & sql server as database. I have two columns in database let's say "name" & "insertedTime" where "insertedTime" contain the time when the "name" is inserted. My work is to fetch data for a time period, let's say for last one hour or last two hours. how do I do this? what will be the query? I hope I have made you understand what is my requirement.

Comment: Can you show some of the SQL that you have tried? You seem to be asking us to do it for you instead of asking us for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like homework so instead;

In C# use the timespan object to get the time an hour ago.

Connect to the database in a number of ways.

Create the sql in it's hardcoded form and run it to verify you are getting results.

Replace the date/time sql with the string version of the timespan string

re-run the sql.

If you have a go for us and post what code you have tried we'll be more inclined to give you better advice and even code.